# Custom class is not working in wp_nav_menu. Please tell me What's wrong in my code?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two file first is header.php.

I want to add custom class in my menu but it's not working. If you have any solution please tell me. I am already before sometime. But now i am forgot.

```
$defaults = array(
'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
'container_class' => 'top-menu-container',
'container_id'    => 'cssmenu',
'menu_class'      => 'menu',
'menu_id'         => 'menu-top-menu1',
);
echo wp_nav_menu( $defaults);
```

functions.php code is following

```
register_nav_menu('header-menu','Top Menu');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already working.. I guess you have done some other mistake as the parameter you have send and throwing the same 'menu class'

By the way you dont have to echo `wp_nav_menu()` function..

Furthur More: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Comment: It's working properly. But i don't have add the menu from the admin panel.